# Probability of $3$ people in a room of $5$ having the same birthday

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability that, amongst five people in a room, three have the same birthday?

I was wondering about this twist on the birthday problem. I am not a major stats guy so I want your help.

Comment: Do you mean exactly three have the same birthday, or at least three? (The two values will be very close, of course.)

Comment: That depends, what is the probability distribution of birthdays? Is it given to you?

Answer (score 2):

Barring leap years and [nonuniform birthday distributions](http://jonathanwstokes.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/US-Birthdays.png), the probability of *exactly* three having the same birthday is
$$\tag1{5\choose 3}\cdot \frac{364^2}{365^4}\approx 0.000075$$
For exactly four, we get $5\cdot \frac{364}{365^4}\approx0.0000001$ and for five $\frac1{365^4}\approx 0.000000000056$, so $(1)$ is also a good approximation for the question about *at least* three having the same birthday.

---

Comment: That's a curious graph. I mean, what's wrong with May!? (And what's with November, while we're at it?)

Comment: May has one more day than April and June. November has one fewer day than each of October/December. @tomasz

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I meant that in a more +9 months way. But I guess that explains May just fine. Still, August/November is a little weird with the around 0.2% jump over July/October. Worse weather in November keeps people home? :)